# $location.hash() - Not running rest of JS. Weird behavior?

Tags: angularjs

Trying to do a simple scroll to the top of my page when the user clicks the 'edit' button. For some reason, when I try to set the $location.hash, it will not run any code following it.

It will put the value into the console, and in the browser address bar, but nothing after.

If you click 'edit' again, (the location value will be in the address bar, i.e. - sitename.com/#/send#top), and the rest of my code will run as expected.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
scrollToLoc = function(loc) {
  $location.hash(loc);
  $anchorScroll();
  console.log(loc);
};

$scope.doEdit = function(item) {
  scrollToLoc('top');
  $scope.request = item;
};
```

Comment: For such URL location hash is going to be `#send#top` which is not what you expect I guess.

Comment: @dfsq Is there a better way to accomplish this basic function in Angular? I am following this http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll